# How to initialize a defined variable with a type of _IO_FILE and pass it as FILE& to a function?

Tags: c++, file

I want to use _IO_FILE and initialize it by a file path.

I defined f:

_IO_FILE f;

but I cannot init it by a file name and then pass it to func1 which is defined as follows:

I tried by using fopen(filename,"r"); but it does not work.

```
Class1 c;
FILE * f;
f=fopen("filename","r");
c.func1(l, f);

int Class1 :: func1 (List& _list, FILE& _file)
```

I should not change the func1.

Comment: `f` is a pointer, but `func1` takes a reference. Therefore you must pass `func1(l, *f)`

Comment: I know, but I should not change func1, is any way I can pass it as FILE&?

Comment: I can change f definition.

Comment: Yes I just showed how.

Comment: Show me the line where you call the function.

Comment: It added a new error: prototype for ‘int int Class1 :: func1 (List& _list, FILE& _file) does not match any in class ‘Class1’  if I pass f without fopen, it does not show this error.